# How to clear Haneke memory cache effectively on iOS?

Tags: ios, caching, haneke

Main memory cache is bloating as user requests more number of images. As user session progresses, main memory size increases which applies excess pressure on memory. This is causing out of memory exception.

Comment: By ```Main memory cache``` do you mean ```in memory cache``` ?

Comment: @danypata : Yes, you got that right

Answer (score 1):

You can clear your cache memory using following methods

Shared.dataCache.clearMainMemory()

Shared.imageCache.clearMainMemory()

Shared.JSONCache.clearMainMemory()

Shared.stringCache.clearMainMemory()

Comment: What version did this apply to?
In current Haneke I see no such method/function private or public.